# ADD Constraint to ALTER DOMAIN ERROR

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, alter

When I execute:

```
ALTER DOMAIN public.remainingamount
    ADD CONSTRAINT "chk_remainingAmount" CHECK (remainingAmount > 0);
```

I recevied the following message in pgAdmin 4:

> ERROR:  column "remainingamount" does not exist SQL state: 42703

The column exists. I can see it in de sidebar! As evidence, when I execute te following line:

```
ALTER DOMAIN public.remainingamount
    ADD CONSTRAINT "chk_remainingAmount" CHECK (remainingAmount > 0);
```

I receive the message:

> ERROR:  type "remainingamount" already exists SQL state: 42710

How can I add a new constraint to an existing domain?

Comment: Very likely you forgot double quotes around `remainingAmount`. If that is not the problem, please show the domain definition (and fix the question, because it is unlikely that you get different error messages for the same statement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only variable you can use in `CHECK` constraint of a `DOMAIN` is `VALUE`. Assuming that the base type is `money:`

```
ALTER DOMAIN public.remainingamount
    ADD CONSTRAINT "chk_remainingAmount" CHECK (VALUE > 0::money);
```

Per [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdomain.html)

> CHECK (expression)
>
> (...)
>
> Currently, CHECK expressions cannot contain subqueries nor refer to variables other than VALUE.

Comment: ERROR:  operator does not exist: money > integer
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883

Comment: The error message says clearly what should you do... See the updated answer.